# Adding Base 36 to Base 10 conversion

Tags: vbscript, radix

I am trying to build on [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416311/base-conversion-function-in-vbscript) that works to convert a number to the specified base.

In my case I have a vbs script that is looking up a serial number and is outputting the alphanumeric character (base 36) to a txt file.

I would like to add to the txt file the base 10 value of the serial number. So I get an output like this:

```
Serial Number:  ABC1234
Service Code:   22453156048
```

This is my starting point. This script runs and gives me a txt file with the Serial Number.

```
On Error Resume Next

' Initialize WSH objects
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")

' Initialize WMI
Set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

' Find client machine name
Set ComputerInfo = WMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
For Each temp In Computerinfo
  WorkstationName = WNetwork.ComputerName
Next

Set Bios = WMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_BIOS")
For Each temp In Bios
  SerN = temp.SerialNumber
Next

' Create Logfiles
Dim sDateTimeStamp
sDateTimeStamp = cStr(Year(now())) & _
                 Pad(cStr(Month(now())),2) & _
                 Pad(cStr(Day(now())),2) & _
                 Pad(cStr(Hour(now())),2) & _
                 Pad(cStr(Minute(now())),2) & _
                 Pad(cStr(Second(now())),2)

Function Pad(CStr2Pad, ReqStrLen)
  Dim Num2Pad

  Pad = CStr2Pad
  If Len(CStr2Pad) < ReqStrLen Then
    Num2Pad = String((ReqStrlen - Len(CStr2Pad)), "0")
    Pad = Num2Pad & CStr2Pad 
  End If
End Function

Set LogFile = FSO.CreateTextFile("c:\logs\" & WorkstationName & "_" & sDateTimeStamp & ".txt")

Set EnviromentVariables = Shell.Environment("PROCESS")
LogFile.Writeline("Serial Number:" & space(2) & SerN)
```

But when I try to add the script from the linked post I do not get any output file.

```
On Error Resume Next

' Initialize WSH objects
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")

' Initialize WMI
Set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

' Find client machine name
Set ComputerInfo = WMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
For Each temp In Computerinfo
  WorkstationName = WNetwork.ComputerName
Next

Set Bios = WMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_BIOS")
For Each temp In Bios
  SerN = temp.SerialNumber

  Function ToBase(ByVal n, b)
    b = 10
    n = SerN
    If b < 2 Or b > 36 Then Exit Function
    Const SYMBOLS = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    Do
      ToBase = Mid(SYMBOLS, n Mod b + 1, 1) & ToBase
      n = Int(n / b)
    Loop While n > 0
  End Function

  SrvCode = ToBase(SerN,10)
Next

' Create Logfiles
Dim sDateTimeStamp
sDateTimeStamp = cStr(Year(now())) & _
                 Pad(cStr(Month(now())),2) & _
                 Pad(cStr(Day(now())),2) & _
                 Pad(cStr(Hour(now())),2) & _
                 Pad(cStr(Minute(now())),2) & _
                 Pad(cStr(Second(now())),2)

Function Pad(CStr2Pad, ReqStrLen)
  Dim Num2Pad

  Pad = CStr2Pad
  If Len(CStr2Pad) < ReqStrLen Then
    Num2Pad = String((ReqStrlen - Len(CStr2Pad)), "0")
    Pad = Num2Pad & CStr2Pad 
  End If
End Function

Set LogFile = FSO.CreateTextFile("c:\logs\" & WorkstationName & "_" & sDateTimeStamp & ".txt")

Set EnviromentVariables = Shell.Environment("PROCESS")
LogFile.Writeline("Serial Number:" & space(2) & SerN)
LogFile.Writeline("Service Code:" & space(3) & SrvCode)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit >> https://web.archive.org/web/20190717135154/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com:80/webtech/032400-1.shtml

I was unable to get the calculation to run using the ToBase Function. But with some more googling I found the above link and I was able to use the referenced function to get the desired output. This now allows me add to a existing script to get the express service code when doing a remote lookup of a Dell computers Service Tag.

So here is the final working script that gives the expected output.

```
' Initialize WSH objects
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")

' Initialize WMI
Set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

' Find client machine name
Set ComputerInfo = WMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
For Each temp In Computerinfo
  WorkstationName = WNetwork.ComputerName
Next

Function baseN2dec(value, inBase)
  'Converts any base to base 10

  Dim strValue, i, x, y

  strValue = StrReverse(CStr(UCase(value)))

  For i = 0 To Len(strValue)-1
    x = Mid(strValue, i+1, 1)
    If Not isNumeric(x) Then
      y = y + ((Asc(x) - 65) + 10) * (inBase ^ i)
    Else
      y = y + ((inBase ^ i) * CInt(x))
    End If
  Next

  baseN2dec = y
End Function

Set Bios = WMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_BIOS")
For Each temp In Bios                                
  SerN = temp.SerialNumber                            
  SrvCd = baseN2dec(SerN, 36)
Next

' Create Logfiles
Dim sDateTimeStamp
sDateTimeStamp = cStr(Year(now())) & _
                 Pad(cStr(Month(now())),2) & _
                 Pad(cStr(Day(now())),2) & _
                 Pad(cStr(Hour(now())),2) & _
                 Pad(cStr(Minute(now())),2) & _
                 Pad(cStr(Second(now())),2)

Function Pad(CStr2Pad, ReqStrLen)
  Dim Num2Pad

  Pad = CStr2Pad
  If Len(CStr2Pad) < ReqStrLen Then
    Num2Pad = String((ReqStrlen - Len(CStr2Pad)), "0")
    Pad = Num2Pad & CStr2Pad
  End If
End Function

Set LogFile = FSO.CreateTextFile("c:\logs\" & WorkstationName & "_" & sDateTimeStamp & ".txt")

Set EnviromentVariables = Shell.Environment("PROCESS")
LogFile.Writeline("Serial Number:" & space(2) & SerN)
LogFile.Writeline("Service Code:" & space(3) & SrvCd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested function definitions aren't allowed in VBScript. This should be raising a syntax error, despite the global `On Error Resume Next` (which you shouldn't be using in the first place).

Put the function definition somewhere in the global scope (outside the loop), e.g. by changing this:

```
Set Bios = WMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_BIOS")
For Each temp In Bios
  SerN = temp.SerialNumber

  Function ToBase(ByVal n, b)
    b = 10
    n = SerN
    If b < 2 Or b > 36 Then Exit Function
    Const SYMBOLS = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    Do
      ToBase = Mid(SYMBOLS, n Mod b + 1, 1) & ToBase
      n = Int(n / b)
    Loop While n > 0
  End Function

  SrvCode = ToBase(SerN,10)
Next
```

into this:

```
Function ToBase(ByVal n, b)
  If b < 2 Or b > 36 Then Exit Function
  Const SYMBOLS = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
  Do
    ToBase = Mid(SYMBOLS, n Mod b + 1, 1) & ToBase
    n = Int(n / b)
  Loop While n > 0
End Function

Set Bios = WMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_BIOS")
For Each temp In Bios
  SerN = temp.SerialNumber
  SrvCode = ToBase(SerN,10)
Next
```

Make sure to remove the lines `b = 10` and `n = SerN`. They're messing up the values passed to the parameters `b` and `n`.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip on the error resume. I have updated to put the function before the lookup as you indicated and now it is generating a log file again but the SrvCode is blank in the txt file. When I use SrvCode = ToBase(SerN,10) the log entry is blank, but when I try to take out the varible by using SrvCode = ToBase(ABC1234,10) the log file gives a value of 0 which is incorrect.