# Generate 3 digit alphanumeric DATE INDEX

Tags: vbscript, barcode-printing

I have a requirement for a container label, that will have a QR code, part of the code will be a **"3-digit date index starting from 1/1/2017. For example, 1/1/2017 is 000 and 1/31/2017 is 00U. This is the date when Content Label is printed or the parts manufacturing date.:"** I dont know if this date index code is some standard , but if it is I cannot find it anywhere, I need a way to generate it from within bartender barcode software which has vbscript support for when this custom requirements arise, how can we generate this? I was thinking of creating a string containing 0-10 and a-z and then searching for the nth ocurrence (30 in the example given) would give me the U, but I don't know how to handle the middle and leftmost digits once I reach more than 36, like creating my own 39tecimal (is that even a thing) numerical system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Base conversion function in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416311/base-conversion-function-in-vbscript)

Comment: Thank you for the reference, while in bartender vbscript is very limited, the function in the other question could work with some modifications., anyway I managed to do it with builtin bartender serialization functions, not so out of the box but easier than applying a vb function since it would have to be called many times and BT doesnt support this (you have to create a function for each element you want to call it from).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with builtin bartender serialization functions, since VBscript support in bartender is very limited, the suggested answer did not solve my problem regarding how to do it in bartender, but It did help me to understand how to do it in case it had better VB support (it is doable with VBscript in BT but not as easy and customizable).